# Building Allegro 5 Library using TDM-GCC and CMake

Tags: cmake, codeblocks, mingw32, allegro5, tdm-gcc

I am attempting to build Allegro 5 Library using TDM-GCC and CMake. As seen in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aoan.png), I pointed to the correct folders using CMake, but the error I am getting is as follows:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7:
  Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text
  "<!DOCTYPE".

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: It seems that your `CMakeLists.txt` is corrupted or downloaded as a *html* instead of a *text* file.  String `<!DOCTYPE` is a key for html, but `CMakeLists.txt` shouldn't contain it. (And doesn't contain: [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)).

Comment: Where did you get the allegro source from? 5.2.5 is the latest aside from GIT.

Comment: Can you include either (preferably) the text or a screenshot of the `CMakeLists.txt` that you are using to start the build process? It does seem that you are trying to parse a HTML file instead of the correct file.